# Arduino NodeJS SerialPort speed

Tags: node.js, arduino, node-serialport

I have a basic NodeJS script that is sending data to my Arduino and the Arduino is sending data back. Everything works fine if the communication from NodeJS to the Arduino occurs around every two seconds or more. If I go any faster than that, data is no longer being sent back and forth, or possibly my Arduino code is no longer detecting the `readStringUntil()`.

Here is my nodejs code:

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
const parsers = SerialPort.parsers;

const parser = new parsers.Readline({
  delimiter: '\r\n'
});

var port = new SerialPort('/dev/tty.usbmodem1421',{
  baudRate: 9600,
  dataBits: 8,
  parity: 'none',
  stopBits: 1,
  flowControl: false
});

port.pipe(parser);
port.on('open', () => console.log('Port open'));
parser.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log( 'Received: ' + data );
  console.log( '------------------------------' );
});
var counter = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  counter ++;
  switch(counter % 4) {
    case 0:
      port.write( "pin3-on,");
      break;
    case 1:
      port.write( "pin3-off,");
      break;
    case 2:
      port.write( "pin4-on,");
      break;
    case 3:
      port.write( "pin4-off,");
      break;
  }
}, 5000);
```

And this is my Arduino code:

```
String incomingJSON;

void serialSend() {
  // Send serial data
  StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;
  JsonObject& data = jsonBuffer.createObject();
  data["pin2"] = digitalRead(2);
  data["pin3"] = digitalRead(3);
  data["pin4"] = digitalRead(4);
  data.printTo(Serial);
  Serial.println();
}

void serialReceive() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    incomingJSON = Serial.readStringUntil(",");
    if (incomingJSON.indexOf( "pin3-on" ) >= 0) {
      digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
    } else if (incomingJSON.indexOf( "pin3-off" ) >= 0) {
      digitalWrite(3,LOW);
    } else if (incomingJSON.indexOf( "pin4-on" ) >= 0) {
      digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
    } else if (incomingJSON.indexOf( "pin4-off" ) >= 0) {
      digitalWrite(4,LOW);
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  pinMode( 2, INPUT );
  pinMode( 3, OUTPUT );
  pinMode( 4, OUTPUT );
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) continue;
}

void loop() {
  serialReceive();
  serialSend();
  delay( 500 );
}
```

Any idea what may be slowing it down? Or is this just the nature of serial port communication?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a solution, but I have since modified the code above to use JSON both form nodejs to the Arduino and from the Arduino to nodejs:

Here is my nodejs code:

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
const parsers = SerialPort.parsers;

const parser = new parsers.Readline({
    delimiter: '\r\n'
});

var port = new SerialPort('/dev/tty.usbmodem1421',{ 
    baudRate: 9600,
    dataBits: 8,
    parity: 'none',
    stopBits: 1,
    flowControl: false
});

port.pipe(parser);

port.on('open', function() {});

parser.on('data', function(data) {

    console.log( 'Received: ' + data );

});

var counter = 0;

setInterval(function(){

    counter ++;

    switch( counter % 6 )
    {
        case 0:
            port.write( "{3:1}" );
            // console.log( "{3:1}" );
            break;
        case 1:
            port.write( "{3:0}" );
            // console.log( "{3:0}" );
            break;
        case 2:
            port.write( "{4:1}" );
            // console.log( "{4:1}" );
            break;
        case 3:
            port.write( "{4:0}" );
            // console.log( "{4:0}" );
            break;
        case 4:
            port.write( "{3:1,4:1}" );
            // console.log( "{3:1,4:1}" );
            break;
        case 5:
            port.write( "{3:0,4:0}" );
            // console.log( "{3:0,4:0}" );
            break;
    }

}, 2000);
```

And this is my Arduino code:

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

String lastOutgoingJSON;
String nextOutgoingJSON;

void serialSend() {

  // Create a new JSON object
  StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;
  JsonObject& data = jsonBuffer.createObject();

  // Populate JSON object with pin data
  data["2"] = digitalRead(2);
  data["3"] = digitalRead(3);
  data["4"] = digitalRead(4);

  // Convert pin data to a JSON string
  nextOutgoingJSON = "";
  data.printTo(nextOutgoingJSON);

  // Check if JSON data has changed since last time
  if( lastOutgoingJSON != nextOutgoingJSON )
  {
    Serial.println(nextOutgoingJSON);
  }

  // Update the last JSON data wit hthe new JSON data
  lastOutgoingJSON = nextOutgoingJSON;

}

void serialReceive() {

  // Check if there is serial data available
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {

    // Place incoming JSON string into a variable
    String incomingJSON = Serial.readString();

    // Convert JSON string to a JSON object
    StaticJsonBuffer<200> JSONBuffer;
    JsonObject& parsedJSON = JSONBuffer.parseObject(incomingJSON);

    // Check for pin commands and exectue
    if (parsedJSON.containsKey("3"))
      digitalWrite(3,parsedJSON["3"]);

    if (parsedJSON.containsKey("4"))
      digitalWrite(4,parsedJSON["4"]);

  }

}

void setup() {

  pinMode( 2, INPUT );
  pinMode( 3, OUTPUT );
  pinMode( 4, OUTPUT );

  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) continue;

}


void loop() {

  serialReceive();
  serialSend();

  delay( 100 );
  delay( 100 );

}
```